# Masking object to plane

Tags: keyframes, masking

New to Blender, experience in Adobe products.

I have 3 planes filling the camera viewport - they slide in left-to-right overlaying each other. That part was simple enough.

Next I added our logo and did the same thing, left to right slide in. However, I'm trying to get part of our logo (composed of 2 SVGs) to reveal at a different time. The entire logo should slide in with additional slide to reveal the last part.

I would generally accomplish this in After Effects by creating a shape, animating it, and then clipping the layer I want revealed to the animated box. But I'm struggling to do this in Blender. Currently what I've done is create a plane and animate it to reveal the logo as I'd expect and attempted masking it by setting Layer 2 to Mask (And moving the plane to Layer 2) but this is masking all the large scale color planes in the background as well, not just the logo

Additionally, it seems Blender brought our logo SVG in backwards, I had to rotate it along z by 180 and x by 90 but when I apply a material color it doesn't show, when I hit `F12` to see the render it's showing the logo but filled with black.

Comment: You could use another plane as a mask object, just edit the material to hold out other objects on the same layer.

Comment: Have you solved this one yet?

Comment: I did not. I ended up jumping over to After Effects for this particular project. Blender seems super powerful but I was on time constraints. I'll continue tinkering with Blender though.